# Shrink an image to half its height and width in java

Tags: java, image

I am trying to shrink an image to half its height and width. This is what I have so far. I have no clue where to go from there. 
One way to do it is to simply replace a group of pixels from the original image with a single pixel in the new shrunken image which is the average color over the group in the original.
I can also create a new array whose height and width are half the height and width of the image passed in as an argument. Then, insert new pixels into the new image as I figure out what the color values should be.

```
public class ImageManipulation
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    Pixel[][] image = readImage("griff.ppm");

    flipVertical(image);

    writeImage(image,"manipulatedImage.ppm");
}

public static void grayscale(Pixel[][] imageArr)
{
    int height = imageArr.length;
    int width = imageArr[0].length;

    for(int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            Pixel p = imageArr[row][col];

            int grayValue = (p.getRed() + p.getBlue() + p.getGreen())/3;

            p.setBlue(grayValue);
            p.setGreen(grayValue);
            p.setRed(grayValue);

            imageArr[row][col] = p;
        }
    }

}

public static void shrink (Pixel[][] imageArr)
{
    int height = imageArr.length/2;
    int width = imageArr[0].length/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to write all that code yourself :)

```
public BufferedImage shrink(File source, int w, int h) {
    int dstWidth = w / 2;
    int dstHeight = h / 2;
    BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(source);
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(
                                       dstWidth
                                     , dstHeight
                                     , BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, dstWidth, dstHeight, null);
    g.dispose();
    return resizedImage;
}
```